# How do you run rots in a Rails integration test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openid

How do you run [rots](http://github.com/roman/rots) in a Rails integration test? I can run rots from the command line, should I run the command from Ruby or is there a method I can call to get it to run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's best to start rots in `before(:all)` block (for rspec) or `def setup` method (for test unit) and stop it in `after(:all)`/`def teardown` block/method respectively.

To start rots you probably should use something like:

```
rots = IO.popen("rots")
```

and then to stop it:

```
rots.close
```

but be aware this code is not tested.

Comment: Do you mean `rots`? That seems to block until rots exit, so it never leaves the setup. What am I missing?

Comment: The backticks were removed from around rots in my comment.

Comment: Try daemonizing the process (i.e. Send it to background with & at the end of command line).

For stopping grep rots through ps aux and SIGTERM found process.